# Rails 3.2 - installation new app

Tags: ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, bundle-install

First time I install RoR app based on PostgreSQL database and after run the command **rails new psql_app -d postgresql** I get following problem:

```
      ...
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.gitkeep
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.gitkeep
      create  vendor/plugins
      create  vendor/plugins/.gitkeep
         run  bundle install
/Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:243:in `mkdir': Permission denied - /Users/adam/.gem/specs/rubygems.org%443 (Errno::EACCES)
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:243:in `fu_mkdir'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:217:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:215:in `reverse_each'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:215:in `block in mkdir_p'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:201:in `each'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:201:in `mkdir_p'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:125:in `fetch_spec'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/remote_specification.rb:47:in `_remote_specification'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/remote_specification.rb:53:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:101:in `block in __dependencies'
    ....
```

I also tried to re-set up the connection to PostgreSQL database, but without success... still getting this error. When I try to create a new app with MySQL database, I don't get this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is bundler not being able to write to your rvm folder. I expect that the reason it works with Mysql is that the appropriate gems are already installed and were probably installed using sudo and now you're trying to run `rails new` as your current user `adam`.

You could use `sudo rails new psql_app -d postgresql` or alternatively you could fix the permissions in your `~/.gem` directory. To do this you can probably safely type:

`sudo chown -R adam ~/.gem`

This should let you install gems without using sudo.

Comment: The most vital of vital things here is, if you've installed RVM into your home directory (as you should) then **DON'T** use sudo to install gems.

Comment: I would like to solve that without using sudo in the best way. I tried  to set up the permissions by the command you mentioned, but I got the error `Operation not permitted`

Comment: Since you've installed gems (or possibly rvm) with the sudo command (or as root) then you need to be root to fix the permissions. You're meant to run ```sudo chown -R adam ~/.gem```. I've edited my answer the reflect this.

Comment: gems, with rvm are located under `~/.rvm` so @user984621 should type `sudo chown -R adam ~/.rvm`

Comment: I have to admit I've switched to rbenv to avoid the gemset madness!